# create jpg from user selection in autocad?

Tags: autocad

Is there is a way by autocad.net to make a jpg image from user on-screen selection? I googled for that and found something about graphic objects. Is that the only way that draw each entity as a graphic object and then save as jpg?

If so, how can I explode text and draw it as drawn in cad?

Thank you

Comment: JPG may not be the best image format for *drawn* images. Google for comparisons between JPG and PNG, for example.

Comment: jpg  png bmp no problem any raster format

Answer (score 3):

If you want to take a screenshot, here are some articles on the subject :

- http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2009/09/taking-screenshots-of-autocads-main-and-drawing-windows-using-net.html
- http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2007/04/taking_a_snapsh_1.html